# Dynamically Allocated Jagged Arrays with Smart Pointers

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers, jagged-arrays

So I've recently become familiar with (and fell in love with) boost and c++11 smart pointers. It makes memory management SO much easier. And, on top of all that, they can usually still work with legacy code (through the use of the `get` call)

However, the big hole I keep running into is multidimensional jagged arrays. The correct way to do it is to have a `boost::scoped_array<boost::scoped_array<double>>` or `vector<vector<double>>`, which will clean up nicely. However, you cannot get a `double**` out of this easily to send to legacy code.

Is there any way to do this, or am I stuck with non-smart jagged arrays?

Comment: What exactly is the API of your "legacy code"? I don't see how you could possibly pass a jagged array as `double**` - where's the size information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` for storage, unless the structure was highly static.

To produce my array-of-arrays, I'd produce a `std::vector<double*>` via transformation of my above storage, using syntax like `transform_to_vector( storage, []( std::vector<double>& v ) { return v.data(); } )` (`transform_to_vector` left as an exercise to the reader).

Keeping the two in sync would be a simple matter of wrapping it in a small class.

If the jagged array is relatively fixed in size, I'd take a `std::vector<std::size_t>` to create my buffer (or maybe a `std::initializer_list<std::size_t>` -- actually, a `template<typename Container>`, and I'd just `for( : )` over it twice, and let the caller pick what container it provided me), then create a single `std::vector<double>` with the sum of the sizes, then build a `std::vector<double*>` at the dictated offsets.

Resizing this gets expensive, which is a disadvantage.

A nice property of using `std::vector` is that newer APIs have full access to the pretty `begin` and `end` values.  If you have a single large buffer, you can expose a range view of the sub arrays to new code (a structure containing a `double* begin()` and `double* end()`, and while we are at it a `double& operator[]` and `std::size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }`), so they can bask in the glory of full on C++ container-style views while keeping C compatibility for legacy interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in C++11, you should probably work with `unique_ptr<T[]>` rather than `scoped_array<T>`.  It can do everything that `scoped_array` can, and then some.

If you want a rectangular array, I recommend using a `unique_ptr<double[]>` to hold the main data and a `unique_ptr<double*[]>` to hold the row bases.  This would work something like this:

```
unique_ptr<double[]> data{ new double[5*3] };
unique_ptr<double*[]> rows{ new double*[3] };
rows[0] = data.get();
for ( size_t i = 1; i!=5; ++i )
    rows[i] = rows[i-1]+3;
```

Then you can pass `rows.get()` to a function taking `double**`.  This approach can work for a non-rectangular array as well, provided the geometry of the array is known at array creation time so that you can allocate all the data at once and point `rows` to the proper offsets.  (It may not be as straightforward as a simple loop, though.)

This will also give you better locality of reference and memory usage, since you only perform two allocations.  All of your data will be stored together in memory and there won't be additional overhead for the separate allocations.

If you want to change the geometry of the jagged array after creating it, you will need to come up with a principled way of managing the storage for this solution to be applicable.  However, since changing the geometry using `scoped_array` is awkward (requiring specific uses of `swap()`), I wouldn't be surprised if this isn't an issue for you.

(Note that this approach can work with `scoped_array` as well as `unique_ptr<[]>`; I'm simply illustrating it using `unique_ptr` since we're in C++11 now.)